# Fed vs Fed? Do the CIA and FBI work against eachother?

Tags: earth, politics

Working on a domestic spy thriller where amoung other actors the FBI and CIA have different competing domestic agendas.  Looking for thoughts to sort of help "Da Vinci Code" the war on drugs.

Comment: Realzing this sort of situation must have occured sucks no relevance from my question.  Im attempting to connect non fictional dots with metaphorically connected truths.  This is a world building exercise: As the DaVinci Code is to the history of the church, this question is to the history of the war on drugs, lensed by an exaggerated role of federal corruption in an effort to facilitate the design of a super bad ass mother fuckin main charecter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legally, the FBI and the CIA have similar but separate roles.

The FBI operates internally performing counter-terrorism and counter-intelligence (as well as investigating federal crimes in general).

The CIA operates primarily outside the country (think extraordinary rendition) performing similar intel/co-intel and counterterrorism duties.

There are all sorts of ways there could be interfering agendas between the two organizations:

1. An undercover intelligence asset for one could be involved with an organization targeted by the other.
2. A CIA target slips into the US, with pursuit falling under the FBI's
   jurisdiction (or vice versa).
3. CIA funding insurgents (think Bay of Pigs invasion) that are in turn secretly funding terrorist operations in the US.